# merging multiple rows based on unique value using scripting or sql

Tags: sql, shell, unix

I have a file like the one below.

```
cstmrid|PPM|Pre|FBB|Bundle|PPM_R|Pre_R|Bundle_R|FBB_R

11111  |Y  |N  |N  |N     |aaaaa|     |        |     
11111  |N  |Y  |N  |N     |     |pre  |        |

11111  |N  |N  |Y  |N     |     |     |        |FBBr
```

Now I want a file which combines all the three rows and it should be like the one below.Except the cstmr_id all other fields should be appended as it is

```
    cstmrid|PPM1|Pre1|FBB1|Bundle1|PPM_R1|Pre_R1|Bundle_R1|FBB_R1|PPM2|Pre2|FBB2|Bundle2|PPM_R2|Pre_R2|Bundle_R2|FBB_R2|PPM3|Pre3|FBB3|Bundle3|PPM_R3|Pre_R3|Bundle_R3|FBB_R3

    11111  |Y  |N  |N  |N     |aaaaa|     |        |     N  |Y  |N  |N     |     |pre  |        |    N  |N  |Y  |N     |     |     |        |FBBr
```

Can someone help me in achieving this using shell scripting or sql?

Comment: Too much for a simple shell, better use perl or awk.

Comment: Even its with awk or perl, can somebody help me in doing this..